# Type FullCalendarModule does not have 'ɵmod' property

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, angular12

I am using a full calendar npm package using angular. I am getting the following error.

> Type FullCalendarModule does not have 'ɵmod' property.

[image: Full calendar]

Comment: Update your typescript version and check if it resolves?

Comment: I vaguely remember an issue like this. I think you have to add `"postinstall": "ngcc"` to the scripts property of the package.json. ngcc is Angular's compatibility compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps fixed the problem for me:

- **rm -rf node_modules**
- **npm install**
- adding **"postinstall": "ngcc"** to package.json scripts

> ```
> "scripts": { "postinstall": "ngcc" }
> ```